# AWS UDP load balancing with src ip preservation

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp, load-balancing

I have a k8s cluster on AWS that exposes a DNS end point. which means that it needs a static IP and port 53/UDP. also we I that the original source ip of the client will be preserved to the k8s service that accept the request. I have difficulties to find a load balancer that performs it. for now I expose a node with its IP.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Network load balancer now supports UDP

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-udp-load-balancing-for-network-load-balancer/

Answer (score 0):

At this point there is no AWS Load Balancer that supports UDP-LoadBalancing within AWS.

There are currently 3 types of AWS Load Balancers:

- Application Load Balancer

  - Rather sophisticated Layer 7 Load Balancer, which [works with HTTP/HTTPS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html?shortFooter=true#listener-configuration) and therefore only supports TCP
  - You won't get a static IP, which you require
  - **This means UDP won't work, and you don't have a static IP**
- Network Load Balancer

  - High Performance Load Balancer, that works on Layer 4 (Transport), [but only handles TCP Traffic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-listeners.html?shortFooter=true#listener-configuration)
  - The NLB has a static IP Address
  - **Static IP, but no UDP**
- Classic Load Balancer

  - Layer 4 Load Balancer with some Layer 7 features
  - [Only TCP, HTTP, HTTP and SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html)
  - No static IP
  - **Neither static IP, nor UDP support**

This leaves you with the option to build your own Load Balancer, [for which NGINX might be an option](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/). If you try this, I'd recommend setting up multiple load balancer instances for high availability. You could then use Route 53 with [Multi-Value-Answers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-multivalue.html) as a primitive Load-Balancer in front of that, which can do health checks as well. You'd have to handle scaling and stuff like that yourself in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Maurice is correct.

However, there is a way to circumvent this issue by running t3.nano ec2 linux instance which will do the load balancing for you.

You are responsible for scaling it yourself, but in a pinch it works.

Simply add the following to the Userdata (cloudformation YAML example below)

```
UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
            service iptables start
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination ${instance0.PrivateIp}:53
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination ${instance1.PrivateIp}:53
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination ${instance0.PrivateIp}:53
            iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination ${instance1.PrivateIp}:53
            iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
            iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j MASQUERADE
            service iptables save
```

I hope this helps, I was running into some issues with the statistics module, but using the --every 2 ==> --every 1 works 100%, been happy with this solution.